# Validating an expired JWT token behind the servicebus

Tags: c#, security, authentication, jwt, azureservicebus

I have a web API service that allows a user to create a new resource like: `POST /api/resource`. The service then puts the creation request on a service bus and responds with `HTTP 202 Accepted`.

A background process picks up the message from service bus and calls the data access layer to create the resource. However, in order to enforce access control, the data access layer needs to know who the user is to determine whether he/she is allowed to create that resource. **I cannot move this authorization logic into the front-end Web API and use a trusted subsystem for the data access layer.**

[image]

So my solution is to get an access token for the data access layer and store it with the resource creation payload. But that presents a problem. As the message could be processed much later under heavy load, the token may have expired by the time the background process tries to use it. At that moment there is no way to renew the token either.

So I would like to loosen the requirements for the validity of tokens when handled in the backend tier. If the token is valid (trusted issuer etc) except that it is past the expiration time, I want the validation middleware to accept the token.

But there is no way to configure the [`System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwtsecuritytokenhandler(v=vs.114).aspx) token handler to validate expired tokens. Can this be done without writing my own token validator?

Is my approach wrong? What would be viable alternatives to solve this?

Comment: Question: Wouldn't the tokens have been valid (as in authorized) when you get the token to be added to the service bus to begin with? Or am I misunderstanding your question

Comment: @Nkosi Sure, the token is valid when the web service acquires it. But it may be expired by the time the worker service uses it. The service bus creates a temporal decoupling. The message can be process the same second it is put on the service bus or an hour later.

Comment: Right. So even though the token is expired, the contained user associated with the JWT can still be extracted in the back end for access control. How well do you understand JWTs? I ask because my idea may seem manual and you would need to know about decoding JWTs

Comment: I think I understand JWT pretty well, but prefer not to write my own security infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the JWT handler has extensibility points that allow you to keep all the default validation logic and override only the aspect you want to customize - in this case the expiration validation. You can pass your own implementation of TokenValidationParameters.LifetimeValidator to achieve that.

Comment: Oh, that is cool. I was not aware of that. Do you have a link to more info?

Comment: take a look to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/blob/master/TodoListService-ManualJwt/Global.asax.cs - all you need to do is set ValidateLifetime in the TokenValidationParameters to false if you want to ignore the validity. If you want to have a custom validation routine (e.g. accept tokens that expired no more than 30 mins before) you can implement a handler for LifetimeValidator as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I am glad it helps! Does that mean that I get the bounty? :)

Comment: Yes, but bounties have a minimal duration of 24 hours. Don't worry! ;)

Comment: BTW, have you seen this being done in production? Some of my colleagues on the security team feel a little hesitant about this. Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: Your security team is right to be concerned. The expiration check is important. The check can only be relaxed if you know exactly what you are doing and what are the mitigating circumstances that *might* make it ok to change the validation logic. This is also why normally you override the default lifetime validation with your own logic, as opposed to turning off the expiration validation altogether- that would be only for verifying that the JWT options are working as expected.

Comment: When AAD supports delegation tokens as described here (http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-token-exchange-03.html), we could only allow composite tokens to be expired. For now we'll have to resort to allowing Data access service to be called only from the same subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Look at using **Refresh Tokens**. [Auth0 has a good article](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/10/07/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) that explains the background and how they are used, with some sample code.

Comment: Refresh tokens don't work here. They only work for confidential clients (web applications), but these requests are coming from the browser. Even if they were coming from a confidential client, the web API would not have access to the refresh token.